# How to only return a list of inherited instances if defined, otherwise return the base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, oop

I am trying to extend an existing application. I need to implement the ability to define multiple instances of a product while keeping it backward compatible with the existing implementation of the product class.

Current Product class:

```
public class Product {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

Getting a list is done by a simple EF call `context.Products.ToList()`.

Now I want to extend the existing class to be able to define "subproducts". My first try:

```
public class Product {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public List<SubProduct> SubProducts {get; set;}
}

public class SubProduct : Product {
    public string Identifier {get; set;}
}
```

Now, If I have Product instance `ProductA` (€5, with no `subproducts`) and instance `ProductB` (€7) with 2 `Subproducts` "1" and "2", I need to get the following list when fetching all products:

```
Name        Price
ProductA    €5
ProductB-1  €7
ProductB-2  €7
```

How can I fetch a list of all products, but returning a mix of subproducts (without their ancestor) and products?

This has to be returned in a way that this list is compatible with all already existing calls within the application (so that the simple EF call as above would get this list)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need `SelectMany`:

```
var resss = produc
 .SelectMany(p => p.SubProducts ?? new List<SubProduct>() { new SubProduct { Identifier = "" } },
  (parent, child) => new { Name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(child.Identifier) ? parent.Name + "-" + child.Identifier : parent.Name, parent.Price});
```

The Result is:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that give me only a list of subproducts? And I also need to change all the calls in the existing application. I want that calling ```context.Products.Tolist()``` would return both Products (those without subproducts) and Subproducts

Comment: @intrixius No, this will return both `Products` and `SubProducts`. The `SelectMany` flattens queries that return lists of lists, so finally you will have a list with both `Products` and `SubProducts`.

Comment: ok, but that means I have to rewrite all calls throughout the application. Should I also include a filter, to not have the "base" product in the list, like ```context.Products.SelectMany(p => p.SubProducts).Where(p => p.SubProducts.Count()=0).ToList()``` ?

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you can show me how you got a working example so fast?

Comment: It is definitely a nice approach, but it does not solve the backward compatibility thing. This approach would mean I have to change all calls to ```context.Products.ToList()```

Answer (score -1):

In order to be backwards compatible you need [HasDiscriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance) in order to know which row is what entity

[image: discriminator example]

Comment: I know that EF will create a Discriminator field, but I don't see how that would be helping me with what I need